# div margin and width size

Tags: css, html, width

I am not good at CSS and I want to define div position.

When you click the div element, I will add "selected" to class with javascript. But I have a problem about width.

How can I solve that?

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Djmsi)

```
.insideDiv {
    width: 210px;
    margin : 15px;
    float:left;
    height: 210px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

div.selected {
    border: 5px solid #25a9e6;
}

.container{
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the problem with `width` is? This will help ensure you get just the answers you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a 5px border to a div, expands the div's dimensions by 5px in each direction. I believe you want to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.insideDiv`. That way the border won't change the div's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

using toggleClass or addClass

```
$('.insideDiv').click(function(e) {  
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

here my example [Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eiLzw)

Comment: Can you put the example code, or at least the relevant fragment inline in your answer please. This helps with readability and ensures the answer is still useful even if the link goes stale.

Comment: When you click the first div,another div goes down. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Djmsi